# Efficient way of re-using modified csv data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a small Python (3.6) program that mostly has two tasks

1. Read a somewhat large (a couple MB) csv table from a file, modify this data a bit and write it back to another csv file
2. Use the modified csv data for other purposes, namely filling a jinja2 template (no web application though)

For 1. I simply use a combination of csv DictReader and DictWriter that roughly looks like this and that works fine.

```
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_in_file)
keylist = csv_reader.fieldnames.copy()
csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_out_file, dialect='excel', fieldnames = keylist)
csv_writer.writeheader()
for row in csv_object:
  temp_row = modify_stuff(row)
  csv_out_object.writerow( temp_row )
```

Now for 2. in another place of the program I want to use the data I wrote back to `csv_out_object` for filling it into a Jinja2 template. My question is: what is a clever / efficient way of doing this? Should I

- open csv_out_file again via a DictReader again and then loop over this object?
- store the modified rows while looping in part 1 in a separate data structure (e.g. a sequence of OrderedDicts) for later usage?
- look for a way to reuse the actual DictWriter object `csv_out_object`? But so far I have not found a way to iterate over this.

Comment: A couple of MB is a small file, there isn't any meaningful performance difference.

Comment: I think what you want with pandas is easier

Comment: I would read data from file and modify it (without saving) to create new data in memory, and next I would save it (if I would need it) and directly uses modified data in memory with jinja - without reading from file.